# Bootstrap on-the-fly responsive height for elements appended with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

For a prototype website, I have downloadded the free bootstrap template that can be found on this website : http://themes.3rdwavemedia.com/demo/prettydocs/index.html

As you can see on the index page of the template, the six item boxes all have the same size, despite the lenght of their content.  If we inspect the DOM with Firebug, we can see that every item box is defined as a div :

```
<div class="item item-green col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class=item-inner" style="height: 237px;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I edit the index.html page downloadded with the template package, I see that those item div have no predefined height.  The property seems to be added once the page is loadded.

What I want to do is to make the box list dynamic according to a parameter.  Depending on the value of this parameter, there might be 2, 3, 7, 15 boxes, each with a specific icon, color, title, content and link.

In the index.html file, I have added the following onLoad method linked to a personnal Javascript file :

```
<body class="landing-page" onload="addItemBoxes()">
```

Then, in my Javascript file, i have a few fonctions to define the list of boxes to add, and then I use a loop calling a function like this :

```
function addBox(boxId) {
    var boxDetails = getBoxDetails(boxId);
    /*
    Example of boxDetails content : 
    {
        boxId : "1",
        boxTitle : "Cars",
        boxDescription : "This is a page that talks about cars",
        boxIcon : "fa-automobile",
        boxIconSource : "font-awesome",
        boxLink : "cars.html"
    }
    */

    if (boxDetails) {
        //Main div
        var cardsWrapperDiv = document.getElementById("cards-wrapper");

        //Get color from the global var
        var nbrOfItems =  cardsWrapperDiv.getElementsByClassName("item").length;
        var nbrOfColors = COLORS.length;
        var colorIndex = nbrOfItems % nbrOfColors;
        var color = COLORS[colorIndex];

        //Create the box
        var itemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        itemDiv.className = "item " + color + " col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6";

        //Content of the box
        var innerItemDiv = document.createElement("div");
        innerItemDiv.className = "item-inner";

        //Icon
        var iconHolderDiv = document.createElement("div");
        iconHolderDiv.className = "icon-holder";
        if (boxDetails.boxIconSource == 'font-awesome') {
            var i = document.createElement("i");
            i.className = "icon fa " + boxDetails.boxIcon;
            iconHolderDiv.appendChild(i);
        } else if (boxDetails.boxIconSource == 'elegant_font') {
            var iconSpan = document.createElement("span");
            iconSpan.setAttribute("aria-hidden", "true");
            iconSpan.className = "icon " + boxDetails.boxIcon;
            iconHolderDiv.appendChild(iconSpan);
        } else {
            console.log("No icon!");
        }        
        innerItemDiv.appendChild(iconHolderDiv);

        //Title
        var h3 = document.createElement("h3");
        h3.className = "title";
        h3.innerText = boxDetails.boxTitle;
        innerItemDiv.appendChild(h3);

        //Description
        var p = document.createElement("p");
        p.className = "intro";
        p.innerText = boxDetails.boxDescription;
        innerItemDiv.appendChild(p);

        //Link
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.className = "link";
        a.href = boxDetails.boxLink;
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        a.appendChild(span);
        innerItemDiv.appendChild(a);

        itemDiv.appendChild(innerItemDiv);
        cardsWrapperDiv.appendChild(itemDiv);
    }
}
```

The code works fine, except that the boxes have no style height assigned.  When I inspect them with Firebug, I see their definition such as :

```
<div class="item item-green col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <div class=item-inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Therefore, their height depends on the lenght of the content, and this is not pretty at all...

I suspect that the height is assigned with one of the scripts referenced at the bottom of the index.html code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/plugins/jquery-match-height/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

But I have no idea how to call them so that the height problem is fixed.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in the main.js script associated with the template those few lines :

```
/* ======= jQuery Responsive equal heights plugin ======= */
/* Ref: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height */

 $('#cards-wrapper .item-inner').matchHeight();
 $('#showcase .card').matchHeight();
```

If I add the two jquery calls at the end of my personal addBox function, it works.  All the new boxes have a similar size, properly adjusted if the screen size changes.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add style into the div using javascript, you can use:

```
//Content of the box
var innerItemDiv = document.createElement("div");
innerItemDiv.className = "item-inner";
innerItemDiv.style.height="237px"; // This is the line to add
```

Did not test the code, but I think it should work.

Comment: The "237" value is not fixed.  Due to the responsive nature of the site, if I change the size of the window to fit a tablet or a cellphone screen, the height adapts.  Adding it as a property of the div will make it permanent, I think, which is not the expected behavior.

Comment: @nouklea If you want to make it responsive in an easier way, then use media queries in your css. However, if you want to still do it in javascript you can make that value change based on the screen size by using window. onresize and replace the height with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing overflow auto, or use the bootstrap elements class names/ids to adjust size. There is also the option to do nedia queries